# change the color of text filed when it is disabled

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to change color of text filed when it is disabled. I write this code for enabled and disabled. enable works well.

```
  const StyledTextField = styled(({ dir, ...other }) => <TextField {...other} />)`
  label.focused {
  color: green;
 }


.MuiOutlinedInput-root {

direction: ${props => (props.dir ? props.dir : "rtl")};
fieldset {
  border-color: white;
  background-color: rgba(2, 37, 67, 0.5);
}


&:hover fieldset {
  border-color: #87ceeb;
}
&.Mui-focused fieldset {
  border-color: rgba(0, 51, 96, 1);
}

  

fieldset  {
  border-color: white;
  background-color: rgba(2, 37, 67, 0.5);
  
  }
  }

 
}

.MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-disabled {
 
direction: ${props => (props.dir ? props.dir : "rtl")};
fieldset {
  border-color: black;
  background-color:black;
}


&:hover fieldset {
  border-color: black;
}
&.Mui-focused fieldset {
  border-color: black;
 }

  

fieldset  {
  border-color: black;
  background-color:black;
  
}

 
  }
    ${props =>
    props.center &&
   `.MuiOutlinedInput-input {
    text-align: center;
    }`}
   `;

  export default StyledTextField;
```

and here is the my textfiled:

```
  <MyTextField
      id={props.id}
      name={props.id}
      className={props.classes.textField}
      value={props.value}
      onChange={props.onChange}
      margin="dense"
      variant="outlined"
      type={props.type ? props.type : "text"}
      error={props.error}
      fullWidth={props.width ? false : true}
      style={props.width ? { width: props.width } : {}}
      dir={props.dir}        
      inputProps={{ readOnly: props.disable }}
      label={props.message}
      disable={props.disable}
      
      
    />
```

and I use it like this:

```
    <InputRow
                                id="qwe"
                                value={min_quality_threshold}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                classes={classes}
                                disable={true }
                                
                            />
```

in inputRow, I set disable true. so that I becomes disabled and then it should have the style of disabled root. but it doesn't change.

Comment: You should specify that you are using Material-ui…

Comment: @StéphaneVeyret i have it. I import it

Comment: I mean, specify it in your question, for other readers… And probably also in the keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some CSS should do it if you are setting the disabled property on the Input

```
fieldset:disabled  {
  border-color: darkgrey;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you change disable={props.disable} to disabled={props.disable}